# Push Notification Performance Issue [UWP]

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a problem with Push Notification configuration at my UWP project. Actually, the issue is performance. That piece of code (below) registering my app for push notifications makes it much slower at opening.

Some test results (splash screen loading time becuase I use OnStartAsync/Template10)

Code Used => Desktop : 15 seconds, Mobile : 16

Code Not Used => Desktop : 3 seconds, Mobile : 6

```
StoreServicesEngagementManager engagementManager =
 StoreServicesEngagementManager.GetDefault();
await engagementManager.RegisterNotificationChannelAsync();
```

**Mobile device** : Microsoft Lumia 950

**App. target version** : Build 15063

**Microsoft Services Store SDK** 10.1705.16 version

I want to know how people use this SDK and get performance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue within windows Template10. The problem is that it will take time for the `RegisterNotificationChannelAsync` method to make network request. It depends on the network environment how long it takes.

It will block the main thread, if you call the `RegisterNotificationChannelAsync` in the OnStartAsync method directly. So, you need to spend a long time waiting for the app to start.

You could use the `async` method to pack the code that you have mentioned.

```
private async void RegisterEngagementNotification()
{
    StoreServicesEngagementManager engagementManager = StoreServicesEngagementManager.GetDefault();
    await engagementManager.RegisterNotificationChannelAsync();
}
```

This method will be called in a subthread. And the app will start directly.

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    RegisterEngagementNotification();
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MainPage));
}
```

Comment: Zhu when we add async in the Register method above, how does it automatically called in "subthread"? Also, what do you mean by subthread here? (you mean task?)